# Rotate matrix of single model on its own axis

Tags: c++, rotation, glsl, opengl-3

I currently have 5 models displayed in a screen and what I'm trying to do. The following is my vertex shader for translating the models individually so that I can get them to move in different directions:

```
#version 330
layout (location = 0) Position;

uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform vec3 Translation;
uniform mat4 Rotate;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = MVP * * Rotate * vec4(Position + Translation, 1.0); // Correct?
}
```

And to position/move my models individually within the render loop:

```
//MODEL ONE
glUniform3f(loc, 0.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f); // loc is "Translate"
glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(rotationMatrix)); // loc is "Rotate"
_model1.render();
```

Also I do have a glm::mat4 rotateMatrix() that returns a rotation. but when I multiply it with the other matrices within the render loop, the whole scene (minus the camera) rotates to the set angle.

**UPDATE**
How would I be able to apply my rotation to the models independently of the world on their own axis? The problem now is that the model rotates, but from 0,0,0 of the world and not it's own position.

Answer (score 0):

There's are a couple of syntax error in your vertex shader:

- No type for the `Position` variable. Looks from the context like it should be a `vec3`.
- Two `*` signs after `MVP`.

I assume that was those were just an accident while copying the code, and you actually have a vertex shader that compiles.

To apply the rotation described by the `Rotate` matrix before the translation from the `Translation` vector, you should be able to simply change the order in the vertex shader:

```
vec4 rotatedVec = Rotate * vec4(Position, 1.0);
gl_Position = MVP * vec4(rotatedVec.xyz + Translation, 1.0);
```

The whole thing would looks simpler if you defined `Rotate` as a 3x3 matrix, which is sufficient for a rotation.

Comment: That worked, but the only problem I see is that when the model rotates on it's Z-axis, it looks like it's pivoting the entire model around the Z-axis, where X and Y are rotating correctly on their own indivdiual axes. Ever run into that?